# Swift SWRevealController without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I implemented [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) with storyboard and everything works great, but now I would like to program the app without storyboard.

Can someone help me with the implementation? I have a FrontViewController and a MenuViewController. Do I need an extra SWRevealViewController for this and if yes, what do I have to code?

I know there is some information on [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) but it is in Objective-C and I have some problems to write this in Swift 2.0.

Comment: where you struck .....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it as follow.

Create one function `createSlidingMenu` in appDelegate.

```
func createSlidingMenu(){

        let frontViewController = //create instance of frontVC
        let rearViewController  = //create instance of rearVC(menuVC)


        //create instance of swRevealVC based on front and rear VC
        let swRevealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearViewController, frontViewController: frontViewController);
        swRevealVC.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.EaseOut;
        swRevealVC.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30;

        //set swRevealVC as rootVC of windows
        self.window?.rootViewController = swRevealVC!;
}
```

call `createSlidingMenu` in  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and you are good to go.

Comment: got it.. added your method in appDelegate..called it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with `self.createSlidingMenu()`
In the ViewController I created a button which should open the sliding menu with: `menuButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: Selector("revealToggle:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Comment: yes thank you so much!
I also figured out how to switch to a new ViewController:

`revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(NextViewController(), animated: true)`

Comment: good to know that your issue has beed resolved. It would be great if you accept my answer and up-vote it, so it will help community to find working answers.

Comment: you also need to change color of navigation controller, because if you use navigation controller as frontVC then it will always over the window

Comment: What are `frontViewController` and `rearViewController` instantiated as? Trying this gives errors: `let frontViewController = frontViewController()`. And I think this and this are also wrong: `let frontViewController = SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController()`, `let rearViewController  = TestRearViewController()`.

Comment: @MiguelValencia It should be like this
'let frontViewController = HomeViewController()'
'let rearViewController = LeftMenuViewController()'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in swift 3.1)

1. In the StoryBoard create MasterViewController, HomeViewController (embedded in UINavigationController) with storyboardId "HomeViewController", and MenuViewController (embedded in UINavigationController) with storyboardId "MenuViewController".[image]
2. Create MasterViewController class and associate to UIViewController  (MasterViewController) in Storyboard and implements SWRevealViewControllerDelegate protocol (see code)

   ```
   import UIKit

   class MasterViewController: UIViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
       let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController
       let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
       var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

       let menuTable = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "MenuViewController")as! MenuViewController
       let homepage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController

       frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: homepage)
       rearNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuTable)
       rearNavigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

       revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
       revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController
       revealController.delegate = self
       mainRevealController  = revealController

       UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
   }
   ```

   }
3. **As alternative** you could omit MasterViewController and:

   - implement SWRevealViewControllerDelegate in AppDelegate and
   - copy the code of viewDidLoad body wrote above in   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Hitendra, I modify the following code so I can put navigation in Home

AppDelegate.swift

```
func toHome() {
    let frontViewController = HomeController()//create instance of frontVC
    let rearViewController  = MenuController() //create instance of rearVC(menuVC)

    let swRevealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearViewController, frontViewController: frontViewController);
    swRevealVC?.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.easeOut;
    swRevealVC?.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30;

    navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: swRevealVC!)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

LoginController.swift, when user click login button

```
@objc private func login() {
     let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
     appDelegate.toHome()
     return
}
```

HomeController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupLayout() // layout programmatically, I didn't put code here

    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(HomeController.menu))
    self.revealViewController().navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton

}

@objc private func menu() {
    revealViewController().revealToggle(self)
}
```